# Please explain the meaning of this code?

Tags: php, mysql

Could anyone explain this line of code to me. 
What I know is that it fetches data from the database and displays it in a drop down box, but **what is happening in the while loop?** What is `$row[id]` storing and what does `"'>".` mean and what is its purpose?

```
echo "<select name= 'FirstName'>";

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FirstName FROM persons");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<option value='". $row['id']."'>".$row['FirstName']
 . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Perhaps reading a basic MySQL+PHP tutorial would be the best thing to do.

Comment: This is almost the most basic thing you can do with mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provide will dispay select box which contain options which is coming from database

for ex in if you are not fetching from db then you do like this:-

```
<select name ='FirstName'>
 <option value='1'>Name 1</option>
 <option value='2'>Name 2</option>
 <option value='3'>Name 3</option>

</select>
```

And now if your fetching the data from db :-

```
echo "<select name= 'FirstName'>";

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FirstName FROM persons");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<option value='". $row['id']."'>".$row['FirstName'] 
 . '</option>'; // $row['id'] is value for option
}

echo '</select>';
```

Suppose if you have 10 name in database then it will loop 10 times and display 10 option in select box

**EDIT :-**

Do like this :-

```
$id = $_POST['FirstName']; // 'FirstName' is a select box name
```

$id will contain the value like 1 or2 or 3 etc.

Now you have to fetch the data using this id.

Comment: Question is what is happening in the while loop? What is $row[id] storing . So i just explained him that while loop is used to fetch the data from db so that it will display in select box

Comment: @RakeshShetty So If I wish to catch this value so that when user selects an item in the drop down box I can display that data specific to the item selected in the drop down box. Will I have to point to $id or to 'FirstName'? somthing like if($row['id']=="Selected"){} would this be correct syntax and the right way to do it?

Comment: See @AbbasAnsari if you want to display what user is selected after submitting the form then you have to do like this :-                echo $_POST['FirstName']; it will show the value the user has selected. If this is not what you want then please explain in detail

Comment: @RakeshShetty I get the data in accordance to the 'FirstName' in a drop down box. The drop down box contains options of the 'FirstName' example John, Salman, Rakesh etc. Suppose Rakesh  is selected, all the data against Rakesh only has to be displayed. So Will I have to go for $id or to 'FirstName'? If I put a condition after the above code like if($row['id']=="Selected"){} would this be correct syntax and the right way to do it?

Comment: @AbbasAnsari see if suppose <option value="2">Rakesh</option> is selected then you have to go for $row['id']. if you try to print $_POST['Firstname'] you will get the value '2'.

Comment: @AbbasAnsari what you want to do ? you want to show selected = selected in option value ?

Comment: @RakeshShetty I am trying to display data from database in accordance to drop down menu selection.

Answer (score 0):

as long as there is a row in the $query, while loop will fetch it into the $row.

while loop will stop after there is no row to fetch from $query.

does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli_fetch_array()` function fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.

While `$query` has elements it will retrieve them, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

$row['id'] should paste fetched data from `id` column from database. `echo` will output something like:

```
"<option value='1'>John</option>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop creates options (items) for select (dropdown) element. Row[id] this is what would be sent to the server in situation when this option would be selected, '>' sign just close the option tag, and row["FirstName"] this is what user will see in dropdown list (drop down options).

Example: rowid = 1, FirstName = John

```
<option value="1">John</option>
```

Comment: So If I wish to catch this value so that when user selects an item in the drop down box I can display that data specific to the item selected in the drop down box. Will I have to point to $id or to 'FirstName'? somthing like if($row['id']=="Selected"){} would this be correct syntax and the right way to do it?